# Setting SSL on a web site during deployment through VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, iis-7.5, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a deployment task available in VSTS (2017) that sets the "Require SSL" checkbox on a web site? I mean the IIS setting ... I know that in the Visual Studio project there is a property, "SSL Enabled", which I've set to true. But it seems that unless I go to IIS and check "SSL Settings->Require SSL", the web site does not require https.

Is there a way to force this setting as part of a VSTS Release Definition? Or is it the case that when you first set up the web site, you have to set "Require SSL" manually on IIS. I know that subsequent VSTS deployments will preserve this setting once it has been set initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `appcmd.exe` command to set Ssl during build/release.

```
appcmd.exe set config "Contoso" -section:system.webServer/security/access /sslFlags:"Ssl" /commit:apphost
```

[Access Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/access)

The simple way is using [WinRM-IIS Web App Management](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppMgmt/README_IISAppMgmt.md) task.

**Additional AppCmd.exe commands**: `set config "{your web site name}" -section:system.webServer/security/access /sslFlags:"Ssl" /commit:apphost`